# Images, Icons, etc don't display/load when I run my app in VScode using PyQt5. What can I do?

Tags: python, image, ide, pyqt5

I can't manege to get the images or icons loaded. When I run the app in VScode the app works, just without the images. The Icons even have the space but there is nothing in the space where the icon is supposed to be. But running it in the Command Terminal works like it is supposed to.

Using the 'os.path. ...' method, and running it in VScode works every time. But why is it like that?

And, how will the os.path method affect the app when I run it alone? I.e. when I don't run it though the IDE or the Command Prompt (I'm planing to make it a stand alone app, just for fun).

A sample of code that works, the whole app is a bit bigger. (but same principles):

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


        widget = QLabel("")
        image = QPixmap(os.path.join(current_directory, "39487.jpg" ))
        widget.setPixmap(image)
        widget.setScaledContents(True)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Now why when i run this code, the images show. Yet when I remove the os.path method it does not work in the IDE. Running the second version in the Prompt does work though.

Why does the IDE load the code different than the Prompt?

Comment: Welcome to the community! Can you please upload your program? It'll be easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can you print your image's path and show us? Which folder are your images in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative paths in python with respect to where the python command is executed, by default VScode launches python in the root folder of the project so it is not necessarily launched in the script folder, instead you use the command promt from the folder where There is the script and the icons, if you were to run from a higher folder you would also have the same problem. Due to the error that causes relative paths it is better to use absolute paths either explicitly or by constructing it using `os.path`.